# Facebook doesn't fetch all messages

Tags: htc-desire, facebook

When I receive a new message on Facebook, I get the notification properly on the official Facebook app. I open the list of messages and the new message is highlited. The names are correct and the beginning of the message (below the name) is also from the new message. But when I click on it and open the discussion, new messages don't load (i.e., the discussion is consisted of only older messages). Is that maybe because the discussion is too long? What's causing this?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is just the Facebook app being buggy, I've had the same problem.  Try doing a sync.  I believe only the notifications are pushed, and not the actual new data, so you need to sync to grab the new messages.

Comment: As I've said, the application recognizes new messages. When it lists all messages, it does insert a caption of a new message, but when I click on the message, it show only the old part of the discussion.

Comment: I know.  I believe only the old part is shown because *the new part has not been synced*.

Answer (score 0):

You could try clearing the cache of the FB app and have it re-load everything from scratch.

Comment: I did. I deleted all data, set up the account again and the same thing happened. But only with one discussion which is pretty long. :/